# VSCode overrides default HTML viewer

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, default-programs, html, visual-studio-code

I want my default application to open `.html` files to be Chrome but on Ubuntu 18.04 every time I open vscode it overrides my set default. Not sure how to enable this permanently, does anyone know how to stop this change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone already opened an issue on github.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60664

Not a permanent soluation, but delete/mv the xdg-open handler `/usr/share/applications/code-url-handler.desktop` and/or `.local/share/applications/code-url-handler.desktop` will fix current issue until next installation if they do not fix it.

Comment: I ended up deleting that file before realising there was an issue, couldn't find it earlier

Comment: another way to fix this in your file explorer would be to find any `.html` file and do the following:  right click > properties > open as > select your fav browser > set as default