# vscode activity titled 'Visual Studio Code - URL Handler'

Tags: software-installation, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to ubuntu and I uninstalled previous VS Code and reinstalled using the linked article since the one installed using software tool was not updating.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-18-04/#disqus_thread

Now after installation it shows the title next to activities as 'Visual Studio Code - URL Handler':

[image: Screenshot]

Also in the favorite bar, when vscode is opened (using Visual Studio Code icon in favorite bar or any other way), it is shown as a 'Visual Studio Code - URL Handler' instance different from 'Visual Studio Code' which is pinned in favorites.

[Screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS6ac.png)
[Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcXPN.png)

There was no ' - URL Handler' in there before and not in any sources I see online. Can someone tell me what it is and why it occurred. And even if its not something important, how to remove it, it very annoying to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo rm /usr/share/applications/code-url-handler.desktop` worked for me.
However I did have to repeat this after updating VSCode.

Answer was borrowed from part of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1086727).
Github issue is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61989) (wherein someone actually linked to this question).

Comment: That worked for me.
Though it would be annoying to do it for every update. VS code updates every month :(

Comment: That would certainly be annoying...if they hadn't [fixed it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61989#event-1991561699)! :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. After doing this, it simply appears as `code-url-handler`.